# Compare IPAddress column from csv1 and csv2 and if matches get the uptime column from csv2

Tags: powershell

i have 2 csv's with below details

csv1:

```
LNX_HOST_NAME   IPAddress     HOST_ID  SERVER_TYPE
-------------   ---------     -------  -----------
head01.com      10.16.0.11     ABI      WB         
head02.com      10.16.0.12     ABI      WB         
head03.com      10.16.0.14     ABI      WB
```

csv2:

```
Lastboot               IPAddress      SystemUpTime   OSType
--------               ---------      ------------   ------
2/29/2020 3:28:00 AM   10.16.0.10   2698626.75     Unix  
2/29/2020 3:29:00 AM   10.16.0.11   2698560.75     Unix  
2/29/2020 3:34:00 AM   10.16.0.12   2698200.5      Unix
```

Have to compare the IPAddress column from both the csv and return  the common records like below

```
HOST_NAME       IPAddress     HOST_ID  SERVER_TYPE   SystemUpTime
-------------   ---------     -------  -----------   -------------
head01.com      10.16.0.11     ABI      WB           2698560.75  
head02.com      10.16.0.12     ABI      WB           2698200.5
```

Need help to get the logic for this.i wrote the below code which is giving me the unique records, but not able to get the UpTime column

```
$Reference  = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Script\csv2.csv"  | Select-Object -Skip 1
$Difference = Import-Csv -Path "D:\Script\csv1.csv"  | Select-Object -Skip 1


$keys = $Reference | ForEach-Object -MemberName IPAddress | Select-Object -Unique
$DiffVal = $Difference | Where-Object -FilterScript {$keys -Contains $_.IPAddress}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I would use [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) to get the items in the csv files that have similar IPAddress properties and output new objects with all properties you need:

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\csv1.csv'
$csv2 = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\csv2.csv'

$result = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv1 -DifferenceObject $csv2 -Property IPAddress -IncludeEqual -PassThru | 
    Where-Object { $_.SideIndicator -eq '==' } | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $ip = $_.IPAddress
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'HOST_NAME'    = $_.LNX_HOST_NAME
            'IPAddress'    = $ip
            'HOST_ID'      = $_.HOST_ID
            'SERVER_TYPE'  = $_.SERVER_TYPE
            'SystemUpTime' = ($csv2 | Where-Object {$_.IPAddress -eq $ip}).SystemUpTime
        }
    }

# output on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# output to new CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Result.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Result on screen:

```
HOST_NAME  IPAddress  HOST_ID SERVER_TYPE SystemUpTime
---------  ---------  ------- ----------- ------------
head01.com 10.16.0.11 ABI     WB          2698560.75
head02.com 10.16.0.12 ABI     WB          2698200.5
```

Comment: Thanks @Theo. It's working fine. but again there is a problem is my csv1 is having around 850+ records  and csv2 is having 2600+ records. i checked with less data and the output came within no time but when i am trying with the entire data it is taking too much time. i ran it and from last 20 min there is no response. why it is happening

Answer (score 1):

My go-to approach for this is:

- Load the second data set into a hashtable, using the common value as a key
- Use the hashtable to grab the new column values with `Select-Object`:

```
# Create hashtable containing the desired values from csv2
$SystemUptime = @{}
Import-Csv D:\csv2.csv |ForEach-Object {
    $SystemUptime[$_.IPAddress] = $_.SystemUptime
}

# Filter set based on ip addresses found in the second data set
# Use a calculated property to reference the values in $SystemUptime, then export
Import-Csv D:\csv1.csv |Where-Object {
  $SystemUptime.ContainsKey($_.IPAddress)
} |Select-Object *,@{Name='SystemUptime'; Expression = {$SystemUptime[$_.IPAddress]}} |Export-Csv -Path 'D:\Result.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

In case performance matters and you do not want to reinvent the wheel (and don't want to deal with pitfalls and issues as "*what if there are duplicate keys in either list?*").
The [`Join-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join) cmdlet (see also [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848821/in-powershell-whats-the-best-way-to-join-two-tables-into-one)) is based on the approach [@Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) mentioned and takes **less then a second** for joining the two `csv` files with the given sizes:

```
1..2600 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{HOST_NAME = 'head{0:00}.com' -f ($_ % 100); IPAddress = 10, 16, [math]::floor($_ / 256), ($_ % 256) -Join '.'; HOST_ID = 'ABI'; SERVER_TYPE = 'WB'}
} | Export-Csv .\csv1.csv

1..850 | ForEach-Object {
    [pscustomobject]@{lastboot = Get-Date -f s; IPAddress = 10, 16, [math]::floor(3 * $_ / 256), (3 * $_ % 256) -Join '.'; SystemUpTime = Get-Random 999999; OSType = 'Unix'}
} | Export-Csv .\csv2.csv


Measure-Command {
    Import-Csv .\csv1.csv | Join (Import-Csv .\csv2.csv) -On IPAddress -Property HOST_NAME, IPAddress, HOST_ID, SERVER_TYPE, SystemUpTime | Export-Csv .\Result.Csv
}
```

- ***Note1:*** to keep the PowerShell pipeline flowing (which preserves memory), you should try to avoid assigning the file content to a variable (or using brackets `(...)`)
- ***Note2:*** Putting the larger file at the left side of the `Join-Object` command is usually a little faster then the other way around.