# PowerShell Slowness Two Large CSV Files

Tags: powershell, csv, where-clause

I have this script working, but with 100k+ rows in File1 and 200k+ in file 2, it will take days to complete. I got the where.({ part down to less than a second, with both csv files as data tables, but with that route I can't get the data out the way I want. This script outputs the data the way I want, but it takes 4 seconds per lookup. What can I do to speed this up?

I thought containskey somewhere might help, but on PRACT_ID there is a one to many relationship, so not sure how to handle those? Thx.

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\SHC\MSO\DataTable\functionlibrary.ps1" 
[System.Data.DataTable]$Script:MappingTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$File1 = Import-csv "C:\File1.csv" -Delimiter '|' | Sort-Object PRACT_ID
$File2 = Get-Content "C:\File2.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Sort-Object 
$Script:MappingTable = $File1 | Out-DataTable

$Logs = "C:\Testing1.7.csv" 

[System.Object]$UserOutput = @()

foreach ($name in $File1) {

    [string]$userMatch = $File2.Where( { $_.Split("|")[0] -eq $name.PRACT_ID })

    if ($userMatch) {
        # Process the data

        $UserOutput += New-Object PsObject -property @{
            ID_NUMBER                = $name.ID_NUMBER
            PRACT_ID                 = $name.PRACT_ID
            LAST_NAME                = $name.LAST_NAME
            FIRST_NAME               = $name.FIRST_NAME
            MIDDLE_INITIAL           = $name.MIDDLE_INITIAL
            DEGREE                   = $name.DEGREE
            EMAILADDRESS             = $name.EMAILADDRESS
            PRIMARY_CLINIC_PHONE     = $name.PRIMARY_CLINIC_PHONE
            SPECIALTY_NAME           = $name.SPECIALTY_NAME
            State_License            = $name.State_License
            NPI_Number               = $name.NPI_Number
            'University Affiliation' = $name.'University Affiliation'
            Teaching_Title           = $name.Teaching_Title
            FACILITY                 = $userMatch
        }
    }
}


$UserOutput | Select-Object ID_NUMBER, PRACT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_INITIAL, DEGREE, EMAILADDRESS, PRIMARY_CLINIC_PHONE, SPECIALTY_NAME, State_License, NPI_Number, 'University Affiliation', Teaching_Title, FACILITY |
Export-Csv $logs -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does the second file have headers? Can you add the input files (or at least a part) in the question?

Comment: Also have a look at: [Compare IPAddress column from csv1 and csv2 and if matches get the uptime column from csv2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978188/1701026)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `$File2` into a hashtable with the `$_.Split('|')[0]` value as the key - you can then also skip the object creation completely and offload everything to `Select-Object`:

```
$File2 = Get-Content "C:\File2.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Sort-Object 

# load $file2 into hashtable
$userTable = @{}
foreach($userEntry in $File2){
    $userTable[$userEntry.Split('|')[0]] = $userEntry
}

# prepare the existing property names we want to preserve
$propertiesToSelect = 'ID_NUMBER', 'PRACT_ID', 'LAST_NAME', 'FIRST_NAME', 'MIDDLE_INITIAL', 'DEGREE', 'EMAILADDRESS', 'PRIMARY_CLINIC_PHONE', 'SPECIALTY_NAME', 'State_License', 'NPI_Number', 'University Affiliation', 'Teaching_Title'

# read file, filter on existence in $userTable, add the FACILITY calculated property before export
Import-csv "C:\File1.csv" -Delimiter '|' |Where-Object {$userTable.ContainsKey($_.PRACT_ID)} |Select-Object $propertiesToSelect,@{Name='FACILITY';Expression={$userTable[$_.PRACT_ID]}} |Export-Csv $logs -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Get-Content is horrendously slow on large files.  If you're having him read the raw data, he should use [System.Io.File]::ReadAllLines()

Comment: @thepip3r `ReadAllLines` still reads all lines into memory at once. I would go with `ReadLines` instead to read the file in batches. More information at [stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969851/what-is-the-difference-between-file-readlines-and-file-readalllines)

Comment: @thepip3r good point, but might as well pipe `Import-Csv` directly in this case

Comment: @RoadRunner, the slowness with GC, in this case, isn't the fact that it reads all lines into memory, it's that it's terribly slow on large files when compared to [File]::ReadAllLines().

Comment: @RoadRunner, I appear to have mistaken with modern PowerShell... see the edit on my answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not good with the C# stuff. At least I don't fully understand how to access those in the correct fashion. So, leaning towards Mathias if we can iron out that error. Or maybe since File2 uses PRACT_ID as secondary key, containskey might not be possible?

Answer (score 2):

There are a multitude of ways to increase the speed of the operations you're doing and can be broken down to in-script and out-of-script-possibilities:

Out of Script Possibilities:

Since the files are large, how much memory does the machine you're running this on have?  And are you maxing it out during this operation?

**If you are paging to disk, this will be the single biggest impact to the overall process!**

If you are, the two ways to address this are:

1. Throw more hardware at the problem (easiest to deal with)
2. Write your code to iterate over each file small chunks at a time so you don't load it all into RAM at the same time. (very difficult if you're not familiar with it)

In-Script:

- Dont use @() with += (it's really slow (especially over large datasets))

Use instead an ArrayList.  Here is a quick sample of the perf difference (ArrayList ~40x faster on 10,000 and 500x faster on 100,000 entries, consistently -- this difference gets larger as the dataset gets larger or in other words, `@() +=` gets slower as the dataset gets bigger)):

```
(Measure-Command {
    $arr = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

    1..100000 | % {
        [void]$arr.Add($_)
    }
}).TotalSeconds

(Measure-Command {
    $arr = @()
    1..100000 | % {
        $arr += $_
    }
}).TotalSeconds

0.8258113
451.5413987
```

- If you need to do multiple key-based lookups on the data, iterating over the data millions of times will be slow.  Import the data as a CSV and then structure a couple of hashtables with the associated information with `key -> data` and/or `key -> data[]` and then you can do index lookups instead of iterating through the arrays millions of times... will be MUCH faster; assuming you have available RAM for the extra objects..

EDIT for @RoadRunner:

My experience with GC may be old... it used to be horrendously slow on large files but appears in newer PowerShell versions, may have been fixed:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\10MB.txt", ('8' * 10MB))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\50MB.txt", ('8' * 50MB))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\100MB.txt", ('8' * 100MB))
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("$($Env:UserProfile)\Desktop\500MB.txt", ('8' * 500MB))

$10MB  = gi .\10MB.txt
$50MB  = gi .\50MB.txt
$100MB = gi .\100MB.txt
$500MB = gi .\500MB.txt

0..10 | % { 
    $n = [pscustomobject] @{
        'GC_10MB'    = (Measure-Command { Get-Content $10MB }).TotalSeconds
        'RAL_10MB'   = (Measure-Command { [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($10MB) }).TotalSeconds
        'GC_50MB'    = (Measure-Command { Get-Content $50MB }).TotalSeconds
        'RAL_50MB'   = (Measure-Command { [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($50MB) }).TotalSeconds
        'GC_100MB'   = (Measure-Command { Get-Content $100MB }).TotalSeconds
        'RAL_100MB'  = (Measure-Command { [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($100MB) }).TotalSeconds
        'GC_500MB'   = (Measure-Command { Get-Content $500MB }).TotalSeconds
        'RAL_500MB'  = (Measure-Command { [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines($500MB) }).TotalSeconds
        'Delta_10MB'  = $null
        'Delta_50MB'  = $null
        'Delta_100MB' = $null
        'Delta_500MB' = $null
    }

    $n.Delta_10MB  = "{0:P}" -f ($n.GC_10MB / $n.RAL_10MB)
    $n.Delta_50MB  = "{0:P}" -f ($n.GC_50MB / $n.RAL_50MB)
    $n.Delta_100MB = "{0:P}" -f ($n.GC_100MB / $n.RAL_100MB)
    $n.Delta_500MB = "{0:P}" -f ($n.GC_500MB / $n.RAL_500MB)

    $n
}
```

Comment: Hi thepip3r, Can you help me understand where to put this into my script? Thx

Comment: Hi Mathias, I got;Select-Object : Cannot convert System.Object[] to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}. on yours.

Comment: For more clarity, File1 always has 1 PRACT_ID per user. File2 can have many PRACT_IDs assigned to a user in File1, each a different facility. Thx

Comment: @MarcGel, How much RAM on the machine are you using to run this?  Are you ever getting close to 100% of it's use when you run this?

Comment: 16 GB RAM on a VM. Usually have 4 GB available when running this.